# What do I send to a RFID reader when using Android phone in place of tag

Tags: android, flutter, nfc

I am building a Flutter application to store NFC tags an use in place of the stored tags. The tags that I am storing are MiFare Classic and they don't contain any data other than the ATQA (0x004), SAK (0x08) and ID / Serial Number. I have stored all of the tag data on my app, and now want to use the app to respond to a RFID reader in place of the physical tag. I am using the nfc_manager library on Flutter.

Is NFC write used to respond to a RFID tap?
What do I need to send to the RFID reader, and it it is not write, how do I send it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for an Android phone to respond as an Mifare Classic Tag.

"NFC writing" is only used with NFC tags, it cannot be used to communicate to a device operating as another Reader.

You are trying to do something that NFC is not designed for at a Hardware level and NFC!=RFID (they share a low level protocols that you have no control of and they use them in different ways)

Comment: If it is not possible, how do hotel apps that allow your phone to be used as a room key work. What I am trying to do doesn't seem that different.

Comment: They are not trying to be a Mifare Classic Tags (which is a propitiatory non NFC standard Tag). Android phones can emulate a Type 4 Tag and give you control over the ISO 7816-4 protocol level and thus be read by readers that can do this. Also they don't just use the ID for security as the ID provides no security at all. So they use a totally different method to what you are trying to do.